# Is there a place to find which tools are built into Fedora CoreOS (and other distros)?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, distributions, coreos

I am getting ready to do a bare-metal install of Fedora CoreOS in an air-gapped environment, and I'm trying to find a resource that lists the tools the distro comes packaged with. For instance, I know I'm going to need `apache2-utils` and `podman` once I get on this environment, but I want to check whether I'll be able to install these tools without internet access, or if I get them on a network-facing machine and move them over.

Beyond that, what is the best way to find this information for any distro?

I've been searching for quite a while and have not been able to find anything definitive other than which container tools are included. This probably sounds like a complete novice question, and while I think I have a pretty good understanding of how a distro's built-in packages work, I may be mistaken. If that's the case, some clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fedora CoreOS [release notes page](https://getfedora.org/en/coreos?stream=stable) actually has lists of all the packages that are included with the release, so you'll be able to refer to that to determine what packages are included.

For your more general question on how to find this information for any distro, I'm afraid I don't think there's a single answer for that, because the way you'd determine this depends completely on how that distro is packaged, so the method may be completely different from one distro to another.